# Mostrar usuario loggeado en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Saludos, tengo un sistema de log básico, pero quiero que muestre quien esta loggeado, aquí les dejo mi código:

```html
<?php
/* start the session */

session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Check Login</title>
 <meta charset = "utf8" />
</head>


<body>

<?php

 $host_db = "localhost";
 $user_db = "root";
 $pass_db = "****";
 $db_name = "****";
 $tbl_name = "usuarios";

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host_db", "$user_db", "$pass_db")or die("Cannot Connect to Data Base.");

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cannot Select Data Base");

// data enviada desde el formulario
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql= "SELECT*FROM $tbl_name WHERE usuario='$username' and password='$password'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password

if($count == 1){

 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 $_SESSION['start'] = time();
 $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60) ;

 header('location: inicio.php');

}
 else {
 echo "Usuario o contraseña estan incorrectos.";

 echo "<a href='index.php'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>"; 
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la pagina despues que se validan los datos, aqui es donde quiero que aparezca el nombre del usuario loqueado:

```html
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
 
 

} else {
   echo "Esta pagina es solo para usuarios registrados.<br>";
   echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Login</a>";
   

exit;
}?>
```

Comment: Puedes usar el echo de php normal, en tu caso sería `echo $_SESSION['username']` Eso lo acomodas con HTML acorde a lo necesitas.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿En qué vas a usar este sistema de logueo? El código que compartes está lleno de agujeros de seguridad graves y no debería usarse en entornos de producción: usa funciones obsoletas (y eliminadas del estándar PHP), es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL (un usuario podría impersonar a cualquier usuario con un simple valor), el uso de sesiones podría mejorarse... Es una pesadilla desde el punto de vista de la seguridad.

Comment: Gracias, por el consejo, solo es un sistema de login, para algo basico.

Comment: Comprendo que es algo pequeño y básico, pero son problemas muy graves de seguridad y de programación. Por ejemplo, un usuario malicioso podrá acceder a la información de cualquier cuenta usando la contraseña `' or '1`.

Comment: que me recomiendas?

Comment: Usar algo  llamado prepared statements (sentencias preparadas). Ellas te permiten añadir un poco más de seguridad por ejemplo. Es una de las múltiples sugerencias que ayudarán a evitar que tu código sea vulnerable a los ataques mencionados por @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Pero las sentencias preparadas (o parametrizadas) no se pueden usar en las funciones `mysql_*`... uno de Los motivos por los que se desaconsejó el uso de esas funciones, se consideraron obsoletas y se borraron completamente a partir de PHP7. Debería usarse mysqli_* o PDO en su lugar. Y eso es solo uno (aunque el más importante) de los problemas que tiene ese código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo debes imprimir el valor de **username** que guardastes en el **formulario anterior** como variable de sesión. En tu segundo formulario colocas:

```
echo $_SESSION['username']; // Imprimes el usuario que esta logueado.
```

Aquí tu **segundo formulario** con la linea de código extra donde debe ir para que puedas ver el nombre de usuario que ha **logueado** en el sistema:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

    echo $_SESSION['username']; // Imprimes el usuario que esta logueado.

} else {
   echo "Esta pagina es solo para usuarios registrados.<br>";
   echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Login</a>";


exit;
}?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: @LeonardoRodríguez De nada. Me alegra que fue de utilidad. Un Saludo!